# Absolute convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}z_n^2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, absolute-convergence

There are two complex series given ($z \in \mathbb{C}$.
We know that: 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}z_n^2$$
converges absolutely.
We are to show that 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{z_n}{n}$$
also converges absolutely.
I tried to prove it with no success unfortunately. How should the proof look like?

Comment: The converse statement does not hold, as we see with the sequence $z_n=\frac1{\sqrt n}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Cauchy-Schwarz.

**In more detail** *(hidden, place your mouse over to show it):*

> $$ \sum_{n=1}^N \left\lvert \frac{z_n}{n}\right\rvert \leq \sqrt{\sum_{n=1}^N \lvert z_n\rvert^2}\sqrt{\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{n^2}} $$

**Final comment:** instead of Cauchy-Schwarz, you could use the [AM-GM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means) inequality as well.

Comment: You've lost a square (or a square root) there.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Indeed, thanks.

Comment: Where does the GM come in?

Comment: @martycohen $$\frac{\lvert z_n\rvert }{n} \leq \frac{\lvert z_n\rvert^2+\frac{1}{n^2}}{2}$$

Comment: Nice and elementary. Though I see this as an inequality (that is aching for generalization) rather then GM.

Answer (score 3):

This follows from Cauchy-Schwarz, applied to $\sum |z_n|^2$ and $\sum 1/n^2$.